# CMS + Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: php, html

For a university assignment, I have to write the basic functionalities of a CMS. So, I made a table with the pages and their contents. The table looks like this:

```
id  |  page    |  content_en   |  main_image
1   |  About   |  <div class=. |  http://www.
2   |  Contact |  <div class=. |  http://www.
```

I build a standard page which performs `$_GET` for the language and page. It then echo's the image and the content on the right places.
This works perfect. However, if a user wants to edit this with TinyMCE, he needs knowledge about the `<div>`'s and stuff like that. So my question to this community is: How would you change my approach in a way so that a use only edits the real content, but I can still build unique pages by playing around with `<div>`'s and things like that?
I hope I managed to make myself clear...

Comment: I built a stricter CMS, which functioned also as a Templating Engine, so I built websites, then converted them into templates and then the CMS would scan the files for any placeholders and the client could fill in those placeholders. SB, this is like 5% of the whole CMS. If you don't want the end-user to edit the structure then give them R/W Access to only the placeholders you set, which they can use alongside MarkDown to make lists etc. Obviously broad ones like {{CONTENT}} will work also.

Comment: i.e. Multiple DB Rows per page [or serialized array inside content_en] and different placeholders will get filled with different fields.

Comment: Do you have an example on how to replace things like `{{CONTENT}}` on a page?

Comment: I have several examples if you wish:
http://pastebin.com/v3LrNH1T
http://pastebin.com/PzsiZBHV
http://pastebin.com/gxAyNBaE

`$content = str_replace('{{CONTENT}}', $data, $content);` being the main core of it.

Comment: the `selMiddle()` `function` can get the string inbetween `$a` and `$b` from `$s`. For example, `$a = Foo`, `$b = Bar`, `$s = AAAFooHELLOWORLDBarBBB` would return `HELLOWORLD` This can be useful in repeated templating, like for blog comments where a section of markup may need to be repeated.